# how to filter data from redis cache on multiple attributes

Tags: java, caching, redis, redis-cache

I am new to redis and struggling with how to filter certain objects based on certain attributes. I have a simple usecase where, there is a set of 1 million employee object stored in a redis set and I want to filter them on the basis of department and location. For e.g. employee having department as HR and location as LONDON. I have gone through redis documentation and understand that it can be done through scan and match through cli, but struggling to find a example where it can be done programmatically.

Comment: Did you check the Redis module  https://redisearch.com ?

Comment: for this situation I do `HGETALL` and then filter data in own code based on location and HR